# Search for keywords from a string using sqlite and python

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a search box where some text can be entered and results from a database are returned, for example, if I was to search for 'John Smith' the record for all the John Smiths would appear.

However, I would like to make the search less specific, as in if I was to just search for 'John' that record would appear.

**This is my query:**

```
cur = g.db.execute('SELECT name, id, location, education FROM accounts WHERE email=? COLLATE NOCASE OR name=? COLLATE NOCASE OR education=? COLLATE NOCASE', (query, query, query,))
```

As you can see, it also returns a search for not just 'name' but 'location' and 'education' too so I would like the keyword search to apply to these too.

Thanks.

Comment: Isn't `SELECT * FROM phonebook WHERE name LIKE "%John%"` what you want?

Comment: As the search box returns a string like 'John Smith' I would have to split the query so that it is 'John' and 'Smith' and then put it in the query, that is what I'm unsure of. Sorry if I was not clear.

Comment: Then "John Smith".split(" ") returns ["John", "Smith"]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want a `LIKE` statement. Your SQL will look like this:

```
SELECT name, id, location, education FROM accounts WHERE email='John'
COLLATE NOCASE OR name LIKE '%John%' COLLATE NOCASE OR education='John'
COLLATE NOCASE
```

Notice the `LIKE` in `OR name LIKE '%John%'`

---

```
cur = g.db.execute('SELECT name, id, location, education FROM accounts WHERE email=? COLLATE NOCASE OR name LIKE ? COLLATE NOCASE OR education=? COLLATE NOCASE', (query, '%'+query+'%', query,))
```

Again, notice that the `OR` statement on `name` has been changed:

```
OR name LIKE ?
```

With this, though, we also changed the passed parameter:

```
'%'+query+'%'
```

This will wrap your search string in `%` characters, allowing your string to appear anywhere in the field.
To do this with parameters, we need to enclose your parameter in wildcards (`%`)